# Visual Studio is not publishing all folders

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When i publish my site, a folder inside Styles (External) is not publishing. I tryed renaming it and recreating it, but not success. Anyone knows how to solve it?

[image]

Comment: What are the types of files you have included within the External folder? If you right click, properties on the External files themselves, have you set the Build Action to Content?

Comment: LESS files. In the Common folder there are also LESS files and get published.

Comment: If i move the files in this folder to the Common folder it works. So weird.

Comment: Sounds like the Build Action as @DanLister says. Check the properties on the folder and see what the build action says - then compare it to the styles folder.

Comment: Dont have this option on the folder properties.

Comment: Thanks Dan. Thats it. Put a answer so i can mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the types of files you have included within the External folder? If you right click, properties on the External files themselves, have you set the Build Action to Content?